# Set width div preventing other divs to span 100% width

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having some trouble with 100% widths. I have 3 divs, header, content and footer which are relatively positioned. I have set a width of 600px on the header and a width of 100% on the content and footer. However if I resize the browser when I use the horizontal scrollbar the 100% width divs are cut off and don't go all the way across to match the 600px div...how can I fix this?

CSS

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 620px;
}

#content, #footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id = "container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>


#container {min-width:620px;}
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/xN2PV/3/

Point to note. min-width is not supported in IE6. I doubt this matters, if it does you'll need a different solution.

Comment: I don't want them all to be maximum to 620px, when the browser is bigger than 620px I want the content and footer to stretch. At the moment I resize and when the browser is smaller than 620px the 100% width divs are cut off by the browser for some reason.

Comment: I edited the answer a minute ago when I realized that was what you were after. The reason they're being cut off is they are 100% of the VISIBLE window, therefore they will be the size of the window whereas the header will remain 620px

Comment: +1 - the `width: 100%` isn't needed though as it is a block element.

Comment: min-width is not a backwards compatible property, so this example will not work in some older browsers (definitely IE6 and probably IE7). Unfortunately, there's nothing you can really do to get the desired behavior in those browsers without javascript. The market share for those browsers is shrinking, however, so it's not unreasonable to ignore them.

Comment: min-width is supported by IE7, no one in their right mind is supporting IE6 anymore unless they absolutely have to, for example in a situation where corporate machines still run that browser and it's for an intranet rather than internet consumption. That being said if the OP's target market is China he may need another solution: http://www.ie6countdown.com/ The rest of the world moved on from the 10 year old browser 8 years ago lol

Comment: I am aware of all of that. I work in the industry (where I have to support that old POS browser, btw). Doesn't mean it's not pertinent information in case, heaven forbid, he's working on something for a company intranet or China. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set width to "auto" for #content and #footer. Divs, being block elements, will automatically consume 100% of the available width (sans margin if set) in their immediate parent element.

As such, if #content and #footer are contained within #header ***or any other explicitly sized element***, then they will never be wider than the specified width.

Comment: What are the chances content and footer are contained within header?

Comment: You'd be surprised. I've worked on a lot of people's HTML, and it can get pretty hairy.

Regardless, I was just making a point.

Comment: True, but making a point that includes bad practice is sort of against the point of SO to begin with. Just because an answer works doesn't mean it is correct or should be implemented that way. Giving the OP the proper way of doing things is what we should be striving for. Your answer really isn't that different from mine, other than mine shows how it should be achieved by adding a parent element in a semantic way.

Comment: Your example also reinforces the notion that "width:100%" is A) necessary and B) safe, of which it is neither, but it's okay to overlook your inclusion of bad practice, right?

Comment: I fixed the code to address that issue, I just forgot to update the fiddle. Not sure what you think is "unsafe" about it. I'm not trying to start an argument and I didn't mark your answer down, which in all honesty I probably should have. The idea that adding 100% width is on the same level as encapsulating an entire web page in the header is a little on the extreme side. Your answer wasn't a good one deal with it and move on geez.

Comment: Why are you getting so defensive? You pointed out my error, I pointed out yours. You might want to consider wearing a cup if you're going to be so sensitive.

Comment: Oh, and 100% (indeed, any percentage) width is unsafe because it's subject to rounding errors. Two columns, one of 37% width and one of 63% width, should add up to 100% width but, in many cases, will be 100% + 1px. Additionally, it makes working with margin and/or padding next to impossible (even with percentages, because of those rounding errors). Good article on the perils of percentage-based sizing: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/12/why-percentage-based-designs-dont-work-in-every-browser/

Comment: Okay, fair point and thanks for the article. When you said "safe" security was what came to mind and not issues with actual spacing. Silly but eh lol.